# python - avoid unnecessary repetition in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a problem with understanding of how to avoid #redundant repetition in for loops. This program intends to print the divisors of the number in the range 2 and `number`:

```
number = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
for divisor in range (2, number):
    if number % divisor == 0:
        print (divisor)
    else:
        print (number, 'has no divisors in the range')
```

Although it might look so basic for you pros but I am confused with avoiding redundancies.

Comment: The `else` part is not redundant; it is incorrect. It might print `X has no divisors...` even though there are.

Comment: but what if a number has no divisors like 5, how I can print it just once not 4 times!?

Comment: As I said, the problem is *not* printing it multiple times. You shouldn't print it at all, until all the potential divisors have been exhausted. That is, you should print it _outside_ the `for` loop.

Comment: But I tried to print it outside. What happens now is that every time it finds divisors of a number it prints a redundant line of (number, 'has no divisors in the range') at the end. How to avoid this?

Comment: See any of the excellent answers given below (and accept the one that helps the most).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a `count` for divisors and check at the end if its equal to zero.

```
number = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
count = 0
for divisor in range (2, number):
    if number % divisor == 0:
        print (divisor)
        count += 1
if count == 0:
    print (number, 'has no divisors in the range')
```

Comment: It seems quite optimal, thanks. what is the role of count inside if statement exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, you need an additional variable to keep trace whether there was a divisor or not. Also indentation from your `else` block should be removed. Have a look at this code :

```
number = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
is_divisor_found = False
for divisor in range(2, number):
    if number % divisor == 0:
        is_divisor_found = True
        print(divisor)
if not is_divisor_found:
    print(number, 'has no divisors in the range')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a `list` of divisors and append only if it is.

```
number = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
divislbes = []

for divisor in range (2,number):
    if number % divisor == 0:
        divislbes.append(divisor)

print((number, "has no divisors in range.") if not divislbes else "The divisbles of ", number, " are: ", divislbes)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter an integer: 5
5 has no divisors in  range.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest saving a boolean flag that tells you whether you've found a divisor during the loop or not. Something like:

```
number = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
has_divisors = False
for divisor in range (2, number):
    if number % divisor == 0:
        print (divisor)
        has_divisors = True
if not has_divisors:
    print (number, 'has no divisors in the range')
```

Answer (score 0):

Complexity of `range(2, number)` is `O(number)`.

Whereas we can optimise the same to `O(sqrt(number))` as follows:

```
import math

number = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
divisor = 2
have_divisor = False

while divisor <= math.sqrt(number):
    if number % divisor == 0:
        print (divisor)
        print (number/divisor)
        have_divisor = True
    divisor += 1

if not have_divisor:
    print (number, 'has no divisors')
```

Reference : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-divisors-natural-number-set-1/